# Timezone settings django postgresql linux

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, timezone

I have a django website on linux using Postgre SQL in New Jersey server USA (linode.com)
But the users are in a different timezone (Brazil). It is something fool I know, but I do some tests changing settings but nothing positive.

Here is some enviroment settings:
Linux Server (USA):

```
$cat /etc/timezone
Etc/UTC
```

Postgres Console (USA):

```
postgres=# show timezone;
UTC
```

Django settings.py (USA):

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
USE_TZ = True
```

Now the results.

Brazil time now:

> 10:07h

Linux Server time(USA):

> 12:07:52 UTC

Here is something wrong! But ok, I don´t use system local time in my website!

POSTGRE Console (USA):

```
select now();
2018-01-16 12:07:36.967415+00
```

I have a model 'coleta' with a field DATA_LEITURA.

```
data_leitura = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Now I insert a register with 10:07:16h. This is correct time in Brazil!
See:

```
br_tz = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
coleta.data_leitura = datetime(2018, 01, 16, 10, 07, 16, tzinfo=br_tz)
```

In postgre console (USA):

```
SELECT data_leitura FROM coleta;
2018-01-16 15:13:16+00
```

So incorrect! 
When the users (Brazil) open the website, they see:

> 15:13:16

I put this line br_tz = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
This line solves the NAIVE warning and auto convertion!

I am now changing each configuration to see the results... but nothing positive.
I think that are two changes to do.
My first experience with postgres and django using timezones...

What do I have to change!? has Somebody some tip!
Thank you again guys and girls for help, you rock!

Comment: what's the data type of `coleta.data_leitura` column?..

Comment: data_leitura = models.DateTimeField(null=True)